# SLASH constant isn't the same as "/" character [in PHP]?

Tags: add-on-development, php

I recently discovered that the EE/CI's SLASH constant isn't the same as the "/" character. Or, at least, in my plug-in code, `(SLASH == "/")` evaluates to `FALSE`...

They output the same character, though. I'm confused... can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `SLASH` is actually the encoded form of `/`. Here's how it's set:

```
define('SLASH', '&#47;');
```

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. I guess that means the constant isn't the best for use in regular expressions or [pre-parse] string replacements for templates.

Comment: Yeah, I'd just ignore it, the [EE core code does](http://cl.ly/image/1e0I3H2L162n). Depending on what you're doing the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant might be worth a look.

Comment: AMP and other constants are also HTML-encoded. Always good to keep this in mind, they can be the cause of so many weird issues.